# How to make Python refuse negative index values?

Tags: python

Basically I was working on a script where I want to get neighbouring values from a 2D list. I was basically implementing a simple version, where I take the index and add and subtract just one in all directions and catch any out of range indexing with a `try except`.

```
try:
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]][index[1]-1])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]][index[1]+1])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]-1][index[1]-1])
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]-1][index[1]])
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]-1][index[1]+1])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]+1][index[1]-1])
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]+1][index[1]])
    keys.append(keyboard[index[0]+1][index[1]+1])
except IndexError:
    pass
```

But then of course, when I ran this I wasn't catching exceptions when subtracting 1 from 0, I was just indexing the last element of the list instead.

I could test for 0 values, but then that means I'm using 2 different tests to determine what's a valid index, and using `if` statements all the way then I feel it would be messier than this (as I'd have to do nesting in that case). Plus I feel that if I knew of a way to do this it may be valuable in future cases where I intend to only ever use positive values.

Is there a method or way of indexing from a list to force python to refuse negative numbers and only take positive values?

Comment: what should happen if a negative index is passed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In this particular case, it fits best to raise an `IndexError` so that it's consistent with out of index references.

Comment: are the indexes passed in to  functions/methods or can they be used directly? Also if you catch `if n < 0` won't you get a negative index subtracting 1 or is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: If you were changing the behaviour I would have it well documented or people will get a surprise when they try to use a negative index.

Comment: Absolutely it'd be documented well, even though I'm just practicing with it. Though looking at Messa's answer, it's likely I'll work with a subclass instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a subclass of list and redefine `__getitem__` to check for nonnegative indexes.

```
class mylist (list):

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        if n < 0:
            raise IndexError("...")
        return list.__getitem__(self, n)

keyboard = mylist() # instead of []
```

Comment: Yes - I agree that in this case, since the OP is worried about keeping the client code tidy, this is the way to go.

Comment: This is a great answer, cleanest way. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Keep in mind that `n` is not necessarily an integer. If you want to handle things like `my_list[-45:-32]`, you'll need to take `slice` objects into account.